# how to convert Photoshop layer effects("Inner Shadow","Outer Glow","Bevel and Emboss","Color Overlay,"Gradient Overlay") into editable xaml file?

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend-4

I tried to import ".psd" file in Expression blend 4.But there is no way to get ayer effects("Inner Shadow","Outer Glow","Bevel and Emboss","Color Overlay,"Gradient Overlay") as **Editable**.
is there Any other way to convert those layer style to Editable code(xaml file).

Answer (score 0):

A way to get these effect is the use of PixelShaders. 
There are a couple of build-in effects available but all the effects you are referring to.

So there is no easy, out of the box, way to import these as you need the effects first.

A good way to make the effects is by using [Shazzam](http://shazzam-tool.com/default.html)

After creating the effects you will probably still need to edit the xaml by hand to apply the effect to a layer in Blend.